# Makefile failure when shell command does not return anything

Tags: shell, makefile, command, return-value

In my Makefile I use grep to output content of a file where some patterns are not found into another file. However, this works only when there is some output from the grep command and not otherwise. I would prefer not to use any switches to make while running it. This is what I have in my Makefile

```
all:
    @(grep -v -e -define file1 | grep -v -e -libfile | grep -v -e pattern3 >> file2)
```

This works fine if there are lines in file1 that does not contain -define or -libfile but of all the lines in file1 has this pattern and so grep returns nothing then make fails with this error:

```
Makefile.test:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The command works fine in a shell so this has something to do with grep returning -1 and killing make - is there a better way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `grep` is defined to exit with a non-0 code if it doesn't match anything; from the grep(1) man page:

> ```
>    Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were
>    selected, and 2 if an error occurred.
> ```

Since make looks at the exit status of the command it invoked to know whether it succeeded or not, that explains the results you see.

If you want it to always succeed you can suffix it with `true` like this:

```
@grep -v -e -define file1 | grep -v -e -libfile | grep -v -e pattern3 >> file2; true
```

(you don't need the parens: make already invokes each recipe line in its own subshell).

Comment: One can also prepend `-` at the beginning of the recipe to let know `make` that the error should be ignored.